# Using structs like classes in Arduino

Tags: c, struct, arduino

I am trying to get use Arduino Structs as an approximation to classes for a program I am writing. This requires including self referential functions, which is an absolute nightmare given what is and isn't allowed in the Arduino compiler.

Here is a small portion of what I am trying to do:

#### gun.h

---

```
struct Gun {
    int id;
    int damage;
    int (* onFire)(struct * g);
};
```

#### gun_def.h

---

```
#include "gun.h"

extern Gun gunlist[];
extern Gun mygun;

Gun getGun(int id);
```

#### gun_def.cpp

---

```
#include "gun.h"
#include "gun_def.h"

int fire1(struct * g){
    return g->damage;
}
int fire2(struct * g){
    return g->id;
}

Gun gun1 = {00, 10, fire1};
Gun gun2 = {01, 20, fire2};
Gun gun3 = {02, 20, fire1};

Gun mygun = gun1;
Gun gunlist[3] = {gun1, gun2, gun3};

Gun getGun(int id){
    return gunlist[id];
}
```

As you can see, the idea is to have a function pointer inside each instance of the Gun struct, which will then be called by some external function to execute the necessary callbacks for the gun.

There are quite a few issues with this implementation that I have been unable to resolve using typedefs, extra header files, or moving the definitions around to try to overcome the Arduino compilation weirdness. If there is a simpler or easier way to do this, then please let me know. I need this sort of variable callbacks for the system I am trying to implement.

A trace of the errors I'm currently getting are below:

```
In file included from gun_def.cpp:1:
gun.h:5: error: expected identifier before '*' token
In file included from /gun_def.h:1,
                 from gun_def.cpp:2:
gun.h:2: error: redefinition of 'struct Gun'
gun.h:2: error: previous definition of 'struct Gun'
gun_def.cpp:4: error: expected primary-expression before 'struct'
gun_def.cpp:4: error: expected ',' or ';' before '{' token
gun_def.cpp:7: error: expected primary-expression before 'struct'
gun_def.cpp:7: error: expected ',' or ';' before '{' token
gun_def.cpp:11: error: invalid conversion from 'int' to 'int (*)(int*)'
gun_def.cpp:12: error: invalid conversion from 'int' to 'int (*)(int*)'
gun_def.cpp:13: error: invalid conversion from 'int' to 'int (*)(int*)'
```

Comment: What is `struct g` and in c if you don't `typedef struct StructName {} StructName;` you can't use `StructName instance;` for a declaration, you need `struct StructName instance;`

Comment: Line with  `int (* onFire)(struct * g);`: struct tag is missing. Maybe it should be `int (* onFire)(struct Gun * g);`?

Comment: Use #ifndef .. #define guards.  You've #included gun.h twice.

Comment: It appears many of the problems were due to forgetting #ifndef flags on my header files, which fixed many of the errors (multiple definitions)

Besides some wonkiness with the extern definitions, @iharob suggestion fixed the code. Can you tell me how the typedef struct Foo {...} Foo; syntax is supposed to read? I spent a lot of time looking up how typedefs work and did not come across this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can you tell me how the typedef struct Foo {...} Foo; syntax is
>   supposed to read?

To make a long story short, a declaration `typedef T Foo;` defines `Foo` to be a synonym for the type `T`; your example allows to write declarations as e. g.

```
Foo foo1;
Foo foo2;
```

- without the `typedef`, the name `Foo` wouldn't denote a type, but only a structure tag, so it would be required to write

```
struct Foo foo1;
struct Foo foo2;
```

Note: You may be confused if you come from C++, where one can use `Foo` as a type name without having done the `typedef struct Foo Foo;`.

Comment: Ahh, just noticed I never marked an answer. Thanks a lot, this was actually incredibly helpful at the time, although I see how stupid a mistake it is now :)